# Cell unwanted centered vertically in UICollectionView

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I have a UICollectionView which is supposed to display one cell at a time. My problem is, that the cell is centered vertically which is not a desired effect and I can't seem to find where this is caused.

This screenshot shows that the cell has a padding of 46 to the top (as well as to the bottom). The cell is 308 high. Adding the 2x46 that comes to 400px which is the height of the collectionView.

[image]

I have tried to add UIEdgeInsets to the collectionView and set them all to 0 but that didn't do it.

Any idea why my collectionView would do this? Thanks!!

This is how I declare my collectionView:

```
let collectionView: UICollectionView = {
    let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
    layout.scrollDirection = .horizontal
    let cv = UICollectionView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: layout)
    layout.minimumLineSpacing = 0
    layout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 0
    cv.register(AddCardCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "CardCell")
    cv.backgroundColor = .white
    cv.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = false
    cv.isPagingEnabled = true
    cv.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return cv
}()
```

Comment: The cells in the UICollectionViewFlowLayout are always predicted with equal spaces between themselves. If only one cell is placed, it is always located in the center.
You can set inset at the bottom an equal difference in the height of the UICollectionView and cell.

Comment: Gotcha, thanks! Will give that a try!